Adding Speaker Diarization to Existing Google Transcriptions
I have high-quality transcriptions ggenerated using Google’s Chirp2 model (fr-CA). The accuracy of the transcription is excellent, but unfortunately, it lacks speaker diarization, which is a significant issue for my use case. As of now, Google hasn't released diarization support for fr-CA.
I’m looking for a solution that can take my existing transcriptions (in Google JSON format) and the original audio files to add speaker diarization.
I’m aware of several cloud and on-premises solutions that offer diarization-only capabilities, such as:

AWS Transcribe
Microsoft Azure Speech Service
IBM Watson Speech to Text

I've found some local libraries that could potentially be used for speaker diarization:

pyAudioAnalysis: An open-source Python library for audio analysis, which includes some diarization features.
pyannotate: A Python library for audio annotations that can be adapted for speaker diarization.
Kaldi: A powerful speech recognition toolkit that includes diarization modules, though it requires significant setup and expertise.
py-webrtcvad: WebRTC Voice Activity Detector (VAD) for Python, which can be combined with other tools for diarization.

I’d prefer to retain the transcriptions I already have due to their accuracy.
Manually merging a json files would also be an issue (the granularity of the transcription block is pretty low)
Is there any tool, library, or workflow that can integrate diarization into my existing transcription process without needing to regenerate the transcription from scratch?
